# does the IndexedDB Wrapper Dexie.js support all kinds of Web browser?

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb, dexie

I'm planning to use IndexedDB Wrapper Dexie.js for my react.js application.
Does Dexie.js support all kinds of web browsers?
If there is any limitation, kindly let me know

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dexie.js supports all major modern browsers including but not limited to:

- Chrome - all versions younger than 7 years.
- Firefox - all versions younger than 7 years.
- Safari - all versions younger than 3 years.
- Opera - all versions younger than 7 years.
- Edge - all versions younger than 3 years.
- Internet Explorer 11 - partial support
- Edge legacy - partial support

Comment: What about the android browsers?

Comment: Yes, Android browser should also work https://caniuse.com/indexeddb - it's not part of our test matrix but Dexie compiles to ES5 to support all old browsers including IE11 - which is kind of anchient - so Android browser wouldn't be a problem.